# Error in converting Android.mk to android.bp

Tags: android, makefile, android-source

I have tried converting the Android.mk to Android.bp by using the below command but the output was empty

```
 .build/envsetup.sh &&
  make blueprint_tools &&
  androidmk [inputFileName]
```

**output** : Empty

**please find the contents of Android.mk**

mk file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
include $(call all-makefiles-under,$(LOCAL_PATH))
```

please let me know how we can convert the above Android.mk to Android.bp

Comment: First, this question has nothing related to ```java``` and ```android-ndk``` tags. And as for the question - it's empty because your ```Android.mk``` doesn't contain any essential stuff that needs to be converted to ```Android.bp```.

Answer (score 2):

Some statements in `Android.mk` can't be converted by `androidmk`.

The above `Android.mk`, you shown, is equals to the following `Android.bp`:

```
subdirs = [ 
    "src"
]
```

You can replace `src` with your sub-directory contains sub `Android.mk`.

Comment: I have a question, maybe not related, but can we use `include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)` `Android.mk` to compile Android.bp files in subdirectories?

Comment: Answering my own question, I tried and yes, you can use `Android.mk` with `include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)` to compile `Android.bp` files in subdirectories.